# Ledger and Monero GUI v0.14 transaction problem

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I'm using a Ledger Nano S with the Monero GUI wallet v0.14. It looks like the wallet is synced to the latest block. So I sent myself a small test transaction from an exchange but it shows in the wallet as 0 XMR received. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, maybe I'm on the wrong chain or something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You're incurring a bug where the GUI cannot properly decode the amount (and thus shows an incoming transaction of zero XMR). This will be fixed once Ledger Monero app v1.2.x is out.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/aw86rx/updated_information_thread_regarding_the/eiazdte/

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug with v1.1.3 of the Ledger code.  It should just be a parsing bug.  You just can't see your funds for the moment.  You'll want to download v1.2 when Ledger releases it (maybe today), and then rescan the wallet.

If you have trouble getting it to rescan, you can rename the wallet file and open it again, and that will trigger a rescan.